# Code Migration between sandbox

Tags: deployment

we have two developer pro sandboxes in our project. in one sandbox i have access to create and upload an outbound change set. But in another i dont have access to inbound or outbound change sets. Can i deploy code to target sandbox using eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Force.com IDE communicates with Salesforce servers using the Metadata API, which requires a user's profile to have the "Customize Application" and Modify All Data permissions.

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of third party tools you can use to manage deployments between sandboxes, all of which will require the same permissions as the Force.com IDE, as mentioned by Allen Mann.

Assuming you have the ‘Customize Application’ and ‘Modify All Data’ permissions, you could use Eclipse to deploy to your target sandbox.

You may also want to try out [Gearset Deploy](http://www.gearset.com). This hosted tool allows you to compare, inspect and deploy between orgs without use of the command line, and has some pretty nifty features such as dependency analysis and a line-by-line diff viewer to speed up your deployments.

Full disclosure – I’m a part of the Gearset team so I obviously have a bias, but you might find Gearset helps! :)